# Combinatorics problem with geometry

Tags: combinatorics

I have an issue with a combinatorics problem involving the following geometric solid:

[image: Fusion between a hexagonal prism and a hexagonal pyramid]
Fusion between a hexagonal prism and a hexagonal pyramid

We draw, simultaneously and stochastically, three vertices from the solid. What is the probability that these vertices define a plane containing the centre of [ABCDEF]?

I brought two ways of solving this problem and I will present them separately.

## **Solution 1**

We can define three categories of the required planes:

#### 1. The planes perpendicular to face [ABCDEF]

There are three of these planes:

- the one including vertices {V, M, I, F, C}
- the one including vertices {V, L, H, B, E}
- the one including vertices {V, G, J, A, D}

  We can choose three vertices from each of these planes, which makes 
  $ {5}\choose{3} $ for each plane.

  Therefore, there are $ 3 \times $$ {5}\choose{3} $ perpendicular planes to [ABCDEF] including its centre.

#### 2. The planes oblique to face [ABCDEF]

Any plane obtained by choosing two opposed vertices from [ABCDEF] (A and D; B and E; F and C; three possibilities) plus any point that makes an oblique plan to [ABCDEF]. For example, if we draw B and E, drawing also J makes a plane oblique to [ABCDEF]. For each pair of points from [ABCDEF], there are four vertices from the top hexagon which make oblique planes to [ABCDEF] passing through its centre. Note here that if V is drawed, we obtain again a perpendicular plane to [ABCDEF], already counted in the previous category.
Therefore, we will have $3\times 4$ planes oblique to [ABCDEF].

#### 3. The plane that contains [ABCDEF]

This is obtained simply by drawing three vertices from {A,B,C,D,E,F}, making ${6}\choose{3}$ possibilities.

Given that we have 13 vertices to draw from, we have ${{13}\choose{3}}$ possible groups of vertices we can obtain. Hence, the probability should be

## $ P(X) = \frac {3\times{{5}\choose{3}} + 3 \times 4 + {{6}\choose{3}} }{ {{13}\choose{3}} } = \frac{62}{286} = \frac{31}{143} \approx 22$%

## **Solution 2**

We can define four other categories of the required planes:

#### 1. Planes using two vertices from [ABCDEF]

They have to use three pairs of opposing vertices, either A and D, B and E or C and F. For each of these pairs, any of the seven vertices outside of [ABCDEF] will give a plane passing through its centre.

Therefore, there are $ 3 \times 7 $ such planes.

#### 2. Planes using two opposed points from [GHIJLM]

Any plane obtained by choosing two opposed vertices from [GHIJLM] (G and J; H and L; I and M; three possibilities) plus any point that makes a perpendicular to [ABCDEF]. For example, if we draw G and J, drawing either A, D or V (three possibilities) makes a plane containing the centre of [ABCDEF]. 
Therefore, we will have $ 3\times 3$ such planes.

#### 3. The plane that contains [ABCDEF]

This is obtained simply by drawing three vertices from {A,B,C,D,E,F}, making ${6}\choose{3}$ possibilities. Here, the reasoning is exactly the same as exposed in solution 1.

#### 4. Planes obtained from vertix V, one vertix from [ABCDEF] and another from [GHIJLM]

V is a given (1), so we only need to draw one of six vertices from [ABCDEF] and, after obtaining such vertix, we only have two vertices that make a plane that includes the centre [ABCDEF]. Any of these planes is perpendicular to [ABCDEF]. As an example, take the plane defined by points V, A and G.
Therefore, here we have $ 1 \times 6 \times 2 $ such planes.

Given that we have 13 vertices to draw from, we have ${{13}\choose{3}}$ possible groups of vertices we can obtain. Hence, the probability should be

## $ P(X) = \frac {3\times 7 + 3 \times 3 + {{6}\choose{3}} + 1 \times 6 \times 2}{ {{13}\choose{3}} } = \frac{62}{286} = \frac{31}{143} \approx 22$%

In summary, both these solutions bring me 62 cases that favour the mentioned event, giving me this probability. However, the solution I have available states that the probability of this event is actually $ \approx 26$%. If that is so, we have then either 74 or 75 planes meeting the criteria, so I am missing either 12 or 13 planes. Please help, I have no idea where they are.

Thank you and all the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three points at bottom level:

- Any three points:$\;{\large{\binom{6}{3}}}=20$.

Exactly two points at bottom level:

- Two diametrically opposite points at bottom level, and the third point not at bottom level:$\;(3)(7)=21$.

Exactly one point at bottom level:

- Using the top point:$\;(6)(2) = 12$.$\\[6pt]$

  Using two diametrically opposite points at middle level:$\;(3)(2) = 6$.$\\[6pt]$

  For any pair of diametrically opposite bottom level points, there are two trapezoids with the other two points adjacent to each other at middle level, so there are $(3)(2) = 6\;$such trapezoids. For each of the $6$ trapezoids, there are two ways to choose three points with exactly one point at bottom level, so the count is$\;(6)(2) = 12$.

No points at bottom level:

- Two diametrically opposite point at middle level, and the top point:$\;(3)(1) = 3$.

Total count:
$$20 + 21 + (12 + 6 + 12) + 3 = 74$$

Probability:
$$
\frac{74}{\binom{13}{3}}
\approx .2587412587
$$

Comment: "For any pair of diametrically opposite bottom level points, there are two trapezoids with the other two points adjacent to each other at middle level, so there are (3)(2)=6(3)(2) = 6 such trapezoids. For each of the 66 trapezoids, there are two ways to choose three points with exactly one point at bottom level, so the count is(6)(2)=12(6)(2)=12." Can you give me examples of these cases? You stated "for each pair of diametrically opposed bottom level points", which I thought were considered in the "Exactly two points at the bottom level" case. Why isn't this counting the same cases twice?

Comment: @BrunoCAfonso: For example, using the diametrically opposite bottom level points $A,D$, you get the two trapezoids $ADLM$ and $ADIH$. Since there are $3$ pairs of diametrically opposite bottom level points, and each is a base of two such trapezoids, there are $6$ such trapezoids. Each trapezoid yields $4$ triangles generating the plane of the trapezoid, but the ones containing two diametrically opposite points were already counted. Thus, of the $4$ triangles, only two of them are new. So in total, the trapezoids yield $(6)(2)=12$ new triangles.

Comment: @BrunoCAfonso: For example, the trapezoid $ADLM$ yields two triangles not already counted, namely triangles $ALM$ and $DLM$.